# Concatenating Multiple Dataframes on a fuzzy match of row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate n Dataframes where: each has a column that contains names of companies (may not be exactly the same) and other columns (some columns are consistent across tables e.g. Value, Currency, etc. and others are not).

Tables need to be joined on the company name only, any with duplicate columns have their values stored in the cell as a tuple.

e.g.

| Company Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A corp | Cell 2 |
| B corp | Cell 4 |

| Company Name | Date | Leadership | Net Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A corp | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| C corp | Cell 4 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

| Company Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A corp | Cell 2 |
| B corp | Cell 4 |
| C corp | Cell 4 |

| Company Name | Percentage | Comment | HQ | Website |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D corp | Cell 2 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 |
| D corp | Cell 4 | Cell 4 | Cell 4 | Cell 4 |

Here is my code:

```
    def concatenate_tables(self, tables):
        def normalize_name(name):
            if pd.isna(name) or not isinstance(name, str) or name.strip() == '':
                return None
            return name.lower().strip()

        def fuzzymatch(name, existing_entities): # Uses fuzzywuzzy
            if not name or not existing_entities:
                return None
            matches = process.extract(name, existing_entities, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio, limit=1)
            return matches[0][0] if matches and matches[0][1] > 80 else None

        # Ensure all inputs are DataFrames
        if not all(isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame) for df in tables):
            raise ValueError("All elements in 'tables' must be pandas DataFrames.")

        # Collect all unique columns and company names
        all_columns = set(['Company Name'])  # Initialize with 'Company Name' to ensure inclusion
        for df in tables:
            all_columns.update(df.columns)

        all_company_names = set()
        for df in tables:
            if 'Company Name' in df.columns:
                all_company_names.update(df['Company Name'].astype(str).apply(normalize_name).dropna())

        consolidated_data = defaultdict(lambda: {col: [] for col in all_columns})  # Pre-fill with all columns
        for df in tables:
            for _, row in df.iterrows():
                raw_name = row['Company Name']
                norm_name = normalize_name(raw_name)
                matched_name = fuzzymatch(norm_name, all_company_names) if norm_name else None
                effective_name = matched_name if matched_name else norm_name  # Use normalized name if no match

                for col in all_columns:
                    # Append data if column exists in current df, else append None
                    if col in df.columns:
                        consolidated_data[effective_name][col].append(row[col])
                    else:
                        consolidated_data[effective_name][col].append(None)

        # Prepare consolidated rows
        consolidated_rows = []
        for company_name, cols in consolidated_data.items():
            row_data = {"Company Name": company_name}
            for col, values in cols.items():
                # Filter out None values
                non_null_values = list(filter(None.__ne__, values))
                if len(set(non_null_values)) > 1:
                    row_data[col] = tuple(set(non_null_values))
                elif non_null_values:
                    row_data[col] = non_null_values[0]
                else:
                    row_data[col] = None

            consolidated_rows.append(row_data)

        master_df = pd.DataFrame(consolidated_rows)

        return master_df
```

But I can't seem to figure out why this code doesn't return a full table that contains all the columns from each individual table.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) then aggregate with a custom function:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

def f(s):
    s = s.dropna()
    if len(s)>1:
        return tuple(s)
    if len(s)==1:
        return s
    return float('nan')

out = (pd.concat([d.set_index(['Company Name',
                               d.groupby('Company Name').cumcount()])
                  for d in dfs], axis=1)
         .T.groupby(level=0).agg(f).T
         .reset_index('Company Name')
      )
```

Output:

```
  Company Name Comment    Date      HQ Leadership Net Profit Percentage             Value Website
0       A corp     NaN  Cell 2     NaN     Cell 1     Cell 2        NaN  (Cell 2, Cell 2)     NaN
0       B corp     NaN     NaN     NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN  (Cell 4, Cell 4)     NaN
0       C corp     NaN  Cell 4     NaN     Cell 1     Cell 2        NaN            Cell 4     NaN
0       D corp  Cell 2     NaN  Cell 2        NaN        NaN     Cell 2               NaN  Cell 2
1       D corp  Cell 4     NaN  Cell 4        NaN        NaN     Cell 4               NaN  Cell 4
```

Comment: That makes sense, concat, fuzzy match company names and aggregate. Thank you!